# Using React Bootstrap, why can i not change the value of 'margin-left' in my scss, even while using '!important'

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass, next.js, react-bootstrap

So, previously i was using the 'ml-auto' class for my navbar, for my dropdown to push itself all the way over to the left. However, i dont want it to push itself all the way to the left when it goes into a small screen, and the navbar changes into a vertical orientation.

I tried giving my NavDropdown the following class and id

```
className={styles.naviDropdown}
id='navigationDropdown'
```

and apply the following style to it

```
.naviDropdown #navigationDropdown {
    margin-left: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .naviDropdown #navigationDropdown {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

However, this does not work, despite using the !important tag, which i previously thought was a universal trump card that would override everything else, regardless of the high amount of specificity that i already have, but alas, it does nothing.

So i thought, hmm, maybe i have to go all the way up to my custom.scss, which is theming my bootstrap, and already overriding some stuff.

Well, unfortunately, there isn't a $dropdown-margin-left variable that i can easily just change myself, so i attempted to implement it like this

```
.dropdown {
    #navigationDropdown {
        margin-left: auto !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .dropdown {
        #navigationDropdown {
            margin-left: 0 !important;
        }
```

I have been enjoying the bootstrap components, but man if they don't make it as hard as possible for you to simply override their css, it's like they want to force you into doing things a certain way.

***Edit:***
So, ive found out, through the inspector, that for some reason, the id is being applied to the a tag generated by React Bootstrap, not the encompassing div, which is given the proper class. Any ideas what might be going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your element has both the class and the id, your selector needs to be:

```
.naviDropdown#navigationDropdown
```

with no spaces.

Comment: Thank you for that! Didn't realize the space would cause that issue! However, i think there might be a different issue at play, please check my edit.

Comment: @RobbyHoover your edit has nothing to do with your question "why can i not change the value of 'margin-left' in my scss". Adding a different question after receiving an answer is poor etiquette in my opinion. If you want an answer to your second question, why your class and id are not on the element you expect, you would need to at least show us the code you use to generate the html. If we can not see your structure, how could we tell you what you did wrong?